# Cloning a git repository creates a subdirectory where it is cloned to - why?

Tags: git, wordpress

I have a git repository setup at `C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress`.

I'd like to clone it at for instance `C:\xampp\htdocs\newsite`. When I'm in `\newsite` in Git Bash and run `git clone C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\`, I end up with `C:\xampp\htdocs\newsite\wordpress`, when I'd like to have the contents of `\wordpress` in `\newsite`. Is that possible, or am I incorrect in thinking that should be the result?

More information: my intention is to have a plain WordPress install that I can easily clone (the filesystem portion, anyway) to create a new site from. I won't need to have further interaction between the two repositories. Is there a better way to accomplish this than what I'm describing above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the folder is empty, you can use `.` to clone it into the working directory.

```
git clone C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\ .
```

Or you could go up one directory (`cd ..`) and give it the name `newsite`.

```
git clone C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\ newsite
```

Comment: just FYI, this does NOT work if there are already documents IN the newsite folder... which is irritating as heck.  typically, for local development, design assets are in the folder before the site dev begins... which mean an extra !@#$ step when trying to just clone the WP repo into the directory.    does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: @WhiteRau This is mentioned in the answer. Can't you clone to `newsite/src` or similar? Otherwise do you version control your design assets with the source?

Comment: yeah.  tried to go up a level, but no love.  throws same error: directory is not empty.  and the way our shop works, the design assets are all in the site folder because in the past, developers seemed to be unaware of a file structure outside of the project.  O_o  when we start up, we just want to copy down the wp repo and go.  i did, however, find a reacharou..er...workaround thru the Fetch plugin in SublimeText.  :)  still, would be nice to just pull the repo into a directory regardless of what else is there.  we version locally from there.